# Using VBA in Outlook to Send Texts with Emojis

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, emoji

I have some VBA code that I'm using to send texts from Outlook to team members of my project at work.  For some background: for non-AT&T subscribers, we have no issue sending text messages from Outlook by plugging in peoples' numbers en masse into the To: field of Outlook emails.  However, all AT&T subscribers will receive the text as a group message, which we want to avoid.  The non-AT&T subscribers correctly receive individual texts when we do a group send.

We've written some VBA code to loop through a spreadsheet of AT&T numbers so that Outlook sends one email per AT&T number.  This has been working fine for us, however, we were hoping to add some emojis into the texts that we're sending.  I've done a lot of Googling and searching through stackoverflows questions, and I can't seem to find any code built for this purpose.  I'm also a complete noob when it comes to VBA, and I've pieced this solution together thus far from getting help from a coworker and reading through threads on the internet.  This bit about emojis has given me enough trouble that I thought I'd break down and submit this post.

For reference, here is my code:

```
Sub EmojiTest()
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim MobileNumber As String

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

      'Grab list from Excel
      Set xlAtt = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Spreadsheet with AT&T numbers.xlsx")
      xlAtt.Activate
      LastRow = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row

      For i = 1 To LastRow
        xlAtt.Activate
        MobileNumber = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value

        ' Create the message.
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "TeamAccount@work.com"

        With objOutlookMsg
            ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
            Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(MobileNumber)
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

            ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
            .Subject = "Emoji Test"
            .Body = "Text with emojis"
            .Save
            .Send
        End With
      Next i
      Set objOutlook = Nothing
      xlApp.Workbooks.Close
      Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is code I never could have come up with myself due to my complete lack of experience with VBA, and limited experience coding in general.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

`.Body = "Text with emojis"`

To:

`.Body = "\ud83d\ude03"`

Full list available [here](http://www.charbase.com/1f603-unicode-smiling-face-with-open-mouth). Copy the box called Java escape string.

The \u escapes the unicode sequence, so typing "\u" and the UTF-16 sequence should let you insert any Emoji.

Some Emojis are actually 2 seperate char sequences, so you have to chain them together.

Comment: I tried this and it ended up delivering the text that I typed.  As in, instead of a smiley face, it came through as "\u1F601".  I also tried "\u+1F601" which is how it is listed on the site you linked, but the resultant text is still plain text without emojis.

Comment: Can you try this string? `"\uD83D\uDC71"`

Comment: Hm, that didn't work either.  I read somewhere that certain fonts don't have access to Unicode values above a certain point.  Could this be an issue?  I don't even know if that question made sense. 

Thanks for helping with this though.

Comment: Yeah it could be fonts, or the device could be sanitizing the strings somehow so that it doesn't display properly. I'm not too familiar with Unicode myself, but the above string works fine in a C# winforms app.

[Pic here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rocjtcnlknsiw4d/Screenshot%202016-02-11%2017.04.39.png?dl=0) Sorry I couldn't help more, let's hope somebody more knowledgeable has some input on the matter 

Comment: I think the issue happens before the email leaves Outlook because all of the emails in my Sent folder also only display text without emojis.

I'm gonna keep googling.  If I find the solution I'll update this thread.  Thanks again for taking a look at this.

Comment: I found something interesting, haven't gotten far with it but I've at least gotten a strange "?" superimposed on a black diamond show up in my text.

This site explains the usage of the "Chr()" and "ChrW()" functions in VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx. If you write "Chr(34)" quotation marks show up.  I looked up the Unicode character for quotation marks on this website: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm.  It's listed as Unicode character 34 and hex character 22.

Comment: I looked up the symbol I want to text and it's Unicode character 55,356 and hex character 1F389. However, when I email out using ChrW(55356), I get the strange question mark symbol in my text.  Hey, at least a strange symbol is better than plain text.  Here's the Unicode character webpage for what I want to send: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f389/index.htm.

Comment: That website actually has a link on the page of the character I want to email out that shows which fonts support this character.  Here is the page: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f389/fontsupport.htm.  Is there a way to specify the font in my code for the email?  Perhaps that will make the character appear not as a question mark but as the indicated Unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution at this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/6pq1r1/vba_how_can_i_write_emojis_using_chrw/).

As per this, you paste smiley in an Excel cell and then read the cell value, it will be string with length 2, find the code of these 2 characters using AscW() and then chain them using Chrw, e.g. to have a smiley you can use ChrW(-10179) & ChrW(-8638).

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
Sub EmojiTest()
   Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
   Dim MobileNumber As String
   Dim strbody As String

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

      'Grab list from Excel
      Set xlAtt = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Spreadsheet.xlsx")
      xlAtt.Activate
      LastRow = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row

      For i = 1 To LastRow
        xlAtt.Activate
        MobileNumber = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value

        ' Create the message.
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Team@work.com"
        strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI Symbol>&#127881;Congrats!<p>Paragraph 2.<p>Paragraph 3.</BODY>"
        With objOutlookMsg
            ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
            Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(MobileNumber)
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

            ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
            .Subject = "Emoji Test"
            .HTMLBody = strbody


            .Save
            .Send
        End With
      Next i
      Set objOutlook = Nothing
      xlApp.Workbooks.Close
      Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Basically, I had to convert my message into HTML.  I did that using, "Dim strbody As String" at the top, and then using ".HTMLBody = strbody" in my With statement.  Once I did that, it was trivial to use the HTML hex code to enter in my emoji.  Here is a page with the HTML hex code that I used (&#127881): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f389/index.htm.

Learned a lot about using VBA doing this, so it was fun.

Thanks for your help Sam.